# Custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver order problem

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a custom HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.

```
public class DeviceKeyParameterArgumentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    private static final List<String> deviceKeyParamNames = CollUtil.newArrayList("key", "deviceKey");

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(@NonNull MethodParameter parameter) {
        BaseUser user = SecurityUtils.getUser();
        String parameterName = parameter.getParameterName();
        return Objects.nonNull(user) && StrUtil.isNotBlank(user.getDeviceKey())
                && CollUtil.contains(deviceKeyParamNames, parameterName);
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument(@NonNull MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
            @NonNull NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) throws Exception {
        return SecurityUtils.getUser().getDeviceKey();
    }

}
```

Below is my configuration

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        resolvers.add(new DeviceKeyParameterArgumentResolver());
    }

}
```

I want it to execute before RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.

But the custom ones in RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#getDefaultArgumentResolvers will be added later.

My need is to assign values to parameters before reaching the controller.

please help me thanks.